# Specifying the name of a video when src is dataURL

Tags: javascript, html

Using JS I creating a video from a series of screen grabs from a canvas element. E.g.

```
let encoder = new Whammy.Video(25); //25 is fps

for(...) {
  //do stuff on canvas every x ms
  ....

  //get a dataURL from the canvas
  let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');

  //add the dataURL to the encoder
  encoder.add(dataURL);
}

// Now we want to create a video from the array of data urls

encoder.compile(false, (webm_output) => {

  //webm_output is a blob

  //create dataURL from blob
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(webm_output);

  let vid = documentGetElementById('myVid');

  vid.src = url;   

 })
```

This all works, however, if the user would like to download the video (using in built controls), the name of the video is a random string.

Is it possible to manually specify the name?

Comment: The name of the downloading video is always the same as stored on your server.

Comment: The video is not stored on the server. It gets creating dynamically use an HTML5 canvas element.

Comment: whatever the name of the video is inside your src attribute, the same will be the name of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

On this [demo](http://antimatter15.com/whammy/clock.html):

```
<a style="" id="download" download="clock.webm" href="blob:[blob-url]">Download WebM</a>
```

The video name and extension is provided using the `download=` attribute.

Comment: this does not answer to question, he wants to use built-in controls. not an anchor tag.

Comment: @codebuilders I believe you can't do that. `<video />` doesn't support custom naming of the file, it will always get the file name from the source url.